# Flatten facet.pivot from solr query in R

Tags: r, json, solr

I'm trying to flatten a `facet.pivot` from a `solr` query.

I've came across this page: https://rdrr.io/github/ropensci/solr/man/pivot_flatten_tabular.html#heading-1

which says there is a function (pivot_flatten_tabular) that does it, but, after installing the package `solrium` the function does not appear.

Any ideas of why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

maintainer of `solrium` here: I changed the pkg name form `solr` to `solrium`. The `pivot_flatten_tabular` fxn is still there, its not exported though, you can access it with triple colon `solrium:::pivot_flatten_tabular`

Here's an example facet pivot query with `solrium`

```r
cli <- SolrClient$new(host = "api.plos.org", path = "search", port = NULL)
solr_facet(cli, params = list(q='alcohol', facet.pivot='journal,subject',
    facet.pivot.mincount=10))
```